# Audio upload in php

Tags: php, html

Following i give 2 file one is html file which containes file control and submit button for upload medis like image,audio,video etc.I can upload image using following code but when i used for upload audio files its not working.

---

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file"><span>Filename:</span></label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))

&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

  {
  echo "hello";
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Using above code image uploaded successfully but audio file cannot be uploaded.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does it not work? What error do you get? What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Comment: i get "Invalid file" error message which is in code at the ending of program

Comment: Do `echo $_FILES["file"]["type"]` and make sure it is one of the ones you allow

Comment: Seems redundant to check for all of those types in your if statement, and then check for extensions of the same thing.

Comment: there is a 2mb default upload file size limit built into php.ini make sure your files aren't exceeding that

Comment: I add this line top of the php file but it not display anything

Comment: if it's not displaying anything, then the value may be empty, which may be why your code is failing

Comment: echo $_FILES["file"]["type"]  I put this code top of the file and comment other code but file type is not display

Comment: How can i solve this @Jeff Hawthorne

Comment: >.> You did put a `;` after the line where you echo the file type right? Try putting this  `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);` at very top of your php script to turn error reporting on in the event it is set to off in your php.ini

Comment: @JeffHawthorne: no error displayed

Comment: @Jeff Hawthorne how to upload audio file larger than 2mb?

Comment: @SandunHarshana you may have to change your php settings, i think the default cap is 2 mb in php.ini

Comment: :-) thanks @Jeff Hawthorne.now it's working

Answer (score -1):

From the code that you posted, the only error comes from not closing your FORM tag. Other than that, it looks pretty solid.